# Change color on banner text in Wixsharp

Tags: wixsharp

Is it possible to change the color of the text displayed in the banner when using the default WiXUI_Minimal or do I have to add custom dialogs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it like this.

```cs
project.BannerImage = "black_banner.jpg";
project.LocalizationFile = "default.wxs";
project.WixSourceGenerated += Project_WixSourceGenerated;
```

...

```
private static void Project_WixSourceGenerated(XDocument document)
{
    var product = document.Select("Wix/Product");

    var ui = product.AddElement("UI");

    // Banner Title
    ui.Add(new XElement("TextStyle",
        new XAttribute("Id", "White12"),
        new XAttribute("FaceName", "Tahoma"),
        new XAttribute("Size", "12"),
        new XAttribute("Red", "255"),
        new XAttribute("Green", "255"),
        new XAttribute("Blue", "255")));

    // Banner description
    ui.Add(new XElement("TextStyle",
        new XAttribute("Id", "White8"),
        new XAttribute("FaceName", "Tahoma"),
        new XAttribute("Size", "8"),
        new XAttribute("Red", "255"),
        new XAttribute("Green", "255"),
        new XAttribute("Blue", "255")));
}
```

and then I added this to the file default.wxs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WixLocalization Culture="en-us" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">  
  <String Id="InstallDirDlgTitle" Overridable="yes">{\White12}Destination Folder</String>
  <String Id="InstallDirDlgDescription" Overridable="yes">{\White8}Click Next to install to the default folder or click Change to choose another.</String>
  <String Id="LicenseAgreementDlgDescription" Overridable="yes">{\White8}Please read the following license agreement carefully</String>
  <String Id="LicenseAgreementDlgTitle" Overridable="yes">{\White12}End User License Agreement</String>
  <String Id="MaintenanceTypeDlgDescription" Overridable="yes">{\White8}Select the operation you whish to perform.</String>
  <String Id="MaintenanceTypeDlgTitle" Overridable="yes">{\White12}Change, repair, or remove installation</String>
  <String Id="ProgressDlgTitleInstalling" Overridable="yes">{\White12}Installing [ProductName]</String>
  <String Id="VerifyReadyDlgInstallTitle" Overridable="yes">{\White12}Ready to Install [ProductName]</String>
  <String Id="VerifyReadyDlgRepairTitle" Overridable="yes">{\White12}Ready to repair [ProductName]</String>
  <String Id="VerifyReadyDlgRemoveTitle" Overridable="yes">{\White12}Ready to remove [ProductName]</String>
</WixLocalization>
```